# これでこそ vs これだ use in this sequence

Tags: sentence, particle-で, reading-comprehension

[image]

I'm stumbled on the actual nuance of this sentence.

In the top sentence, the character says that if しき is not with them then it's not "everyone".
To which the third character adds これだよ.

Then the third person adds...

これでこそって思ってるくせに

Which I assume is "You are thinking これでこそ, and yet"

I really can't seem to make sense of why he'd correct him over これだよ. I assume here is "これでこそ" like "with this for sure". "That's how it is." vs "That's how things should be"? would be my reading but I'm not really convinced.

Answer (score 2):

Is this character named アーロン superficially cynical, uncooperative, or tsundere-like in nature? In that case, これだよ can mean something slightly negative like "Oh brother", "This again", or "Come on, I knew this would happen", rather than "This is it!". If the game is voiced, please pay attention to his intonation when he speaks.

On the other hand, これでこそ ("This is it", "This is precisely...") is part of a phrase これでこそ◯◯だ, which is a positive expression used like so:

- これでこそチャンピオンだ！
  This is what makes him a champion!
- これでこそ冒険だ！
  This is what I call a true adventure!

So it seems to me that アーロン said in a somewhat low-spirited tone, "Ah, this again", and is behaving as if he does not agree with the others on the surface. And then モクマ pointed out, "But deep down, you are happy about it too, aren't you?" Does this fit the context?

Comment: That would be correct yeah. I'm not sure how you got the nuances though,, especially regarding これでこそ. Was there some hints grammar wise that indicated it?

Comment: @Kawase_K これでこそ literally translates to "This exactly is....!", so something highly positive and/or exciting is implied.